# Javascript alert и document.write()

Tags: javascript, dom

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <title>111</title>
    <META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=WINDOWS-1251">
</head>

<body>
    <div id=metadata></div>

    <script language="javascript">

        metas = 'a\nb';
        metadata.innerHTML = metas;
        document.write(metas);
        alert(metas);

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Почему правильно отображается только `alert`???

Comment: что значит "правильно" ? `document.write()` стирает предыдущий документ, `\n` не переводит строку в html

Comment: Вы неправильно обращаетесь к элементу с определенным ID. Надо так:  

    document.getElementById('metadata').innerHTML = metas;

Comment: по id можно так обращаться, проверьте сами, на каждый незарезервированный id заводится переменная window.id

@sergiks не подставляйте человека под минусы.

Comment: Проверил. Действительно, `window.metadata` определена и позволяет писать в тот div! Не знал. А вот стирание документа не состоялось в FF – вывело две строки "a b".

@sasha511 если вы хотите видеть a и b на разных строках в странице, выводите вместо `metas` замену `metas.replace('\n','<br>')`

Comment: @sasha511, прописывать переменную как

      metas = 'a\nb';

это верх безрассудства. вы забыли волшебное слово 

    var

Comment: @Deus var ничего не даст здесь, это корневой контекст.

Comment: @eicto, насколько я помню, именно вы когда-то доказали мне исключительную полезность инструкции var.

Comment: метод write - никому не нужный метод, который постоянно вводит в заблуждение начинающих javascript-программистов. Ни разу его не использовал и использовать не буду.

Comment: @Deus, ну я просто говорю, что проблем с синтаксисом здесь нет. Есть проблема с кривыми руками, вообще свои проги лучше как-то так начинать

    (function(){/*тут код*/})();

а если используется jQuery, и оно уже подключено, то так:

    (function($){/*тут код/})(jQuery);

естественно var нужен, иначе переменные будут глобальными

Comment: @sasha511, и вообще- что это за глупость после document.write() вызывать alert(). Вы в своем уме?

Answer (score 2):

Вынесу правильный ответ из комментариев: символ перевода строки `\n` как и остальные whitespace-символы не имеют в HTML силы.

Поэтому при использовании API, принимающих HTML (`innerHTML`, `document.write()`) для перевода строки нужно использовать те же конструкции, которые вы бы использовали в HTML-разметке: `<br>` или `<p></p>`.

Да, и не используйте `document.write()`, это пережиток 1990-х, от него у вас будут только проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

не забудьте кавычки

```
document.write ("<br>");
```